# Does Laravel 4 have to be in the root directory?

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I'm just playing around with Laravel and Composer, and I wanted to know if I can change where Laravel is located, but still be able to run composer in the root?  The root folder is getting really busy with node_modules, bower_components, docs, bin, all my .*rc files, compass.rb, gruntfile.js, bower.js, composer.json, and package.json.

I was hoping I could dump Laravel into its own folder, but still be able to use composer.json to handle dependencies without having to change directories, so I can do all my CLI commands for grunt, bower, and composer at the same level.

Thinking of something very similar to .bowerrc where I can dictate where bower.json and bower components get stored.

Something like, but allow CLI in root for everything:

```
/root
    .git
    /bin
    /bower
        /components
        bower.json
    /config
    /docs
    /laravel
        everything laravel instead of in root
        composer.json? or out in root?
    /node_modules
    /sql
        db.sql
    gruntfile.js
    package.json
    .gitignore
    .gitattributes
    all .*rc files x 6, such as: .bowerrc, .jshintrc, etc
    README.md
    LICENSE.md
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just change the path of the auto-loader in **bootstrap/autoload.php**.

Comment: Does that mean composer.json is out in the root? and change it to require __DIR__.'/laravel/../vendor/autoload.php'; and it will just work and allow CLI in root?  I'm really new to Laravel and Composer so sorry in advance.

Comment: No. You would leave the **composer.json** in the root, and your **vendor** directory would stay in the same place too. But if you move the Laravel files, Laravel will need to know the new path to the autoload file Composer generates, which is now one directory up.

Comment: I get it, since vendor is Composer's equivalent of node_modules or bower_components.  So I'd also change my composer.json autoload classmap key:values to include my laravel folder as well, and autoload would be "require __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';".  Do I keep artisan up in root?  Will it work there? and the only other two files are server.php and phpunit.xml, do they go root or in the laravel folder?  Thanks appreciate the help

Comment: Hmmm not sure why but it doesn't seem to be working for me, it's now looking for vendor in /laravel/vendor instead of in root. Maybe it's better I leave the root directory looking like a bomb went off to save on the hassle it seems to be to build a different hierarchy.